# Why does it matter what side the str[i] is on? when adding to newRev

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, reverse

if it's newRev += str[i] it's hello but if str[i] is first it's reversed why?

```
function rev(str){
  newRev = ''
 for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   newRev = str[i] + newRev
 }
 return newRev
}

console.log(rev('hello'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will try to have a dry run on your code, you will see the values of str[i] comes in the order `h`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o`. So when appending based on your mentioned code, it will make it `olleh` but when it is `newRev += str[i]` which actually means `newRev = newRev + str[i]`, that will append each letter at the end which will result in the correct string `hello`.

Answer (score 1):

becuase 
`newRev += str[i]` is equaliant to

`newRev = newRev + str[i]` ('Momu' = 'Mom' + 'u')

and is different than

`newRev = str[i] + newRev` ('uMom' = 'u' + 'Mom')